# How to delete row in for loop function?

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to delete the second row in every sheet in an excel file. Actually, i have done this.

```
for (i in 1:5) 
    {bulan=read_excel(file, sheet=sheet[i],skip = 2)}
```

but it deletes the first 2 rows. How to only delete the second one? Thanx

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether you would really like to delete a row in your excel sheet or read an excel sheet without a certain row.

Because what your are doing here is actually not deleting rows, but skipping the first two rows when reading the sheets. The function `read_excel` returns a dataframe.
If you want the dataframe without the second row, what you could do is:

```
for(i in 1:5){bulan <- read_excel(file, sheet=sheet[i])
     bulan <- bulan[-2,]
}
```

However, this would not make much sense as is, since `bulan` gets overwritten in every step of the for loop.

If you would like to delete rows in your excel file using R, you could read the file, delete the corresponding row of the dataframe in R, and read the dataframe to an excel file again. Apparently there is am R package called "xlsx" for writing excel files.

Comment: how to delete the second row in R? I mean the code. Is it the same with above?

Comment: Yes, so `bulan[-2,]` is `bulan` without the second row. And if you assign `bulan` to `bulan[-2,]`, the dataframe that you now call bulan does not contain this row. So you removed it.